# Addition of 2 unsigned values in VHDL IEEE numeric_std : why this choice?

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL, the IEEE numeric_std package does not behave as one could expect. The addition of two unsigned values coded on 8 bits is not given on 9 bits, but on 8 bits.

What are the reasons of this choice ?

Comment: You could be pragmatic and note that signatures used in overload resolution (here for the addition operator "+") matching a declaration for an implementing function could only convey a subtype of the return value by a type mark. It's easier to manipulate the operand length. The addition operator  "+" is defined to allow operands of different lengths (for unsigned prepending '0's through concatenation or function resize) to match the greater length. There are also cases when overflow is the correct behavior (e.g. binary counters incremented by "+").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "choice" allows the hardware designer to only handle overflow if it makes sense:

- Ignore the overflow

  `function add_ignore_ovf(a : unsigned(7 downto 0), b : unsigned(7 downto 0)) return unsigned(7 downto 0) is
  begin
      return a + b;
  end function;`

  One time this makes sense for implementing modulo 2 counters.
- Handle the overflow

  `function add_with_ovf(a : unsigned(7 downto 0), b : unsigned(7 downto 0)) return unsigned(8 downto 0) is
     variable a_ext, b_ext : unsigned(8 downto 0);
   begin
     a_ext := '0' & a;
     b_ext := '0' & b;
     return a_ext + b_ext;
  end function;`

Comment: Ok. This default behavior is not (in my opinion!) the most intuitive.

Comment: BTW, the type of the a_ext and b_ext should take a AND b ranges into account. Right ?

Comment: Yup, fixing that would make the example too complicated though, so I just fixed the bit widths.